# Holomorphic problem

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

I have a function $f(z)$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}^-$. I have these information:

1. $f(x+i\epsilon) = f(x-i\epsilon)$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ (the $\epsilon$ is indented as a shorthand for a limit);
2. $f(x+i\epsilon) = - f(x-i\epsilon)$ on $\mathbb{R}^-$;
3. $f(z)=\sqrt{z} + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\right)$ for $|z|\rightarrow\infty$, $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}^-$.

I'm asked to show that $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$.

I tried to write $f(x)=\sqrt{z}+\frac{h(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$. In such a way $h(z)$ is continuos on the whole $\mathbb{C}$ and holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}^-$... If it were holomorphic on the whole $\mathbb{C}$, it would be constant and so $h(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}h(z)=0$... but I cannot see a way to prove that $f(z)$ is indeed holomorpic even on $\mathbb{R}^-$. Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps I found a solution. If I show that for every rectangle $R_h$ with a base on $\mathbb{R}^-$ and height $h$ I have

$$
\int_{R_h}h(z)\mathrm{d}z=0
$$

I solved the problem because one can use Morera's theorem to show that $h$ is holomorphic on the whole $\mathbb{C}$. Is always possible indeed do decompose any path crossing $\mathbb{R}^-$ by some rectangles among which one is "on" $\mathbb{R}^-$ and one "under" $\mathbb{R}^-$. It seems simple, by standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument, to show the equation above (exploiting the continuity of $h$). Does it seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{z}$ denote the square root which branch cut on the negative real axis. Is there a reason $f(z)=\sqrt{z}(1+\frac{1}{z})$ does not satisfy your conditions?

Comment: Well $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{z}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{z}}{z}\neq 0$. I think that $O$ actually means $o$ in this case.